# Ambient Light Value is continuously getting output instead of single output - Flutter, light 3.0.1 , Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to get ambient light sensor value using the
light package - [light 3.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/light) at a single instance(single value) after Image picker is called, but its printing luxValues continuously without pausing even after calling `.stopListening()` function

```
      final light = AmbientLightDetector();
      light.startListening();
     
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: option);
      int luxValue = int.parse(light.luxString);

      light.stopListening();
      logger.i(luxValue);
```

Here is the class with required functions

```
class AmbientLightDetector {
  final logger = Logger();
  String luxString = '';
  Light? light;
  StreamSubscription? subscription;

  void startListening() {
    light = Light();
    try {
      subscription = light?.lightSensorStream.listen(onData);
    } on LightException catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
    }
  }

  int onData(int luxValue) {
    logger.i(luxValue);
    return luxValue;
  }

  void stopListening() {
    subscription?.cancel();
  }
}
```

How can i modify this code to get a single value of ambient light intensity. Please mention any code requirements

I tried using Duration to get a singular value but the code is still printing continuous lux values without stopping

```
      light.startListening();

      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: option);
      int luxValue = await Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 1),
        () {
          // This waits for 1 second and then captures the current lux value
          return int.parse(light.luxString);
        },
      );
      light.stopListening();
```